# I am trying to make JavaScript form project with React. I want to put onChange function inside of input. But how?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to make form project with react but I have a problem. When I click to enter button, the button give true to console. Even the form has not completed. So I want if form is not complete or give error, the enter button give false to console else, enter button give true to console. But I have to do with onChange. So how can I do with onChange this?

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const Contact = () => {
    const [button, setbutton] = useState(false);
    
    const buttonOnClick = () => {
        setbutton(true)
        console.log(`Form submitted, ${button}`);    
    }


    console.log(button);

    return(
<div className="main">
    <form >
    <div className="baslik">
     <div className="container center">
    <h1>Contact Form</h1>
    </div>
    </div>
        <div className="field" >
           <label className="text"> Name And Surname: </label>
           <input className="form" placeholder="Kerem Kurt" required />
        </div>
    

      <button type="submit" className="button" onClick ={() => buttonOnClick()}> Enter </button>
```

Comment: Why is your state variable called "button"? Anyway, you need a state like `const [fullName, setFullName] = useState("");` Next you need `<input value={fullName} onChange={(e) => setFullName(e.target.value)} />`. To submit the form you can add `onSubmit={...}` to <form>. Your current code will probably refresh the page, so I'd either remove the <form> wrapper (you don't need it) or change the button's type to "button" instead of "submit"

Comment: I am sorry, I am sarated new to codding. So ı don't know why, ı called satate variable button. I have one more question,  I have more than one input. For instance e mail, phone number etc. So I want check all of  them.

Comment: no matter what amount of input fields you have you need state for all of them. And you have to create a validator function to validate your form every time you submit

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't care if your form is complete or not. You clicked the button and  it executed the onClick handler. If you want to print false. Please validate your form in onButtonClick() and then use setbutton appropriately. I.e. if you find that your form is invalid set it to false or else set it to true.

You have to manually do that. As you are not using any form validation library. Let me give you an example

```js
  

    import React from "react";
      import { useState } from "react";

        const Contact = () => {
           const [button, setbutton] = useState(false);
           const [inputValue,setInputValue] = useState("")
        
           const buttonOnClick = () => {
             if(inputValue === ""){
               setbutton(false)
             }else{
               setbutton(true)
             }
            
            console.log(`Form submitted, ${button}`);  
         }


        console.log(button);

 return(
    <div className="main">
        <form>
        <div className="baslik">
          <div className="container center">
           <h1>Contact Form</h1>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="field" >
          <label className="text"> Name And Surname: </label>
          <input className="form" placeholder="Kerem Kurt" required value={inputValue} onChange={(e)=>setInputValue(e.target.value)/>
         </div>
        

         <button type="submit" className="button" onClick ={() => buttonOnClick()}> Enter </button> 
        </form>
</div>
```